# Flex serialize Object for webservice php

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, apache-flex, serialization

I have a PHP webservice that has to be retrieved by a html/ajax/jquery page and a flex/air application.

In the jQuery version I pass to .php, via ajax POST, a string that is the result of a .serialize()
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

On flex I talk with the .php via the Webservice class.

How can I serialize, exactly as jQuery does, a flex Object, Array or ArrayCollection so I cann pass to the .php as a serialized String?

Comment: Why not JSON encode it? Take a look at [this](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2006/03/28/tutorial-using-json-with-flex-2-and-actionscript-3/)